Is there an existing abstraction for pass-by-value-or-cloneable-ref in Rust?
This seems to work - it's kind of an analogue of Borrow. Borrow says "I only need a &T, but you can pass a T". My ToValue says "I need a T, but you can pass an &T (if T: Clone)".
I can't find an existing abstraction. Does this already exist? Is there a good reason not to use it?
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96a8d09120f2b4577a635b1bddd0f8e4
trait ToValue<T> {
    fn to_value(self) -> T;
}

impl<T> ToValue<T> for T {
    fn to_value(self) -> T { self }
}

impl<T: Clone> ToValue<T> for &'_ T {
    fn to_value(self) -> T { self.clone() }
}

fn foo_inner(_x: Box<u8>, _y: Box<u16>) {}

fn foo(
    x: impl ToValue<Box<u8>>,
    y: impl ToValue<Box<u16>>,
) {
    foo_inner(x.to_value(), y.to_value())
}


fn main() {
    {
        let x = Box::new(0);
        let y = Box::new(0);
        foo(x, y);
    }
    {
        let x = &Box::new(0);
        let y = &Box::new(0);
        foo(x, y);
    }
    {
        let x = &Box::new(0);
        let y = Box::new(0);
        foo(x, y);
    }
    {
        let x = Box::new(0);
        let y = &Box::new(0);
        foo(x, y);
    }
}


Is that Cow?

As previously mentioned, you are looking for Cow and, as far is behavior is concerned, ToOwned.

Cow is close, but it doesn't have the blanket impls for T and &T where T: Clone that my ToValue has, and therefore it doesn't allow the callsite to be oblivious. e.g. this fails to compile https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=58cfc9a341a10ed8837ff47461b66e8b

actually, it somewhat works with just Borrow + ToOwned, but type inference fails so it needs manual annotation at each callsite https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7350331a7017d72c91e6bf056cb46144
